# Extracting data from JSON using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have this input

```
[{"email":"etu@etu"},{"email":"hg"},{"email":"ismail"}]
```

and I want to extract only the value on the email using bash.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Show your try code Omar... This is not a site where you can find freelancers.

Answer (score 2):

Simply with **`jq`**:

```
echo '[{"email":"etu@etu"},{"email":"hg"},{"email":"ismail"}]' | jq -r '.[].email'
```

The output:

```
etu@etu
hg
ismail
```

Comment: i'm using gitbash, there is a lot of functionality that does not exist in gitbash like jq

Comment: @OmarAmaoun, then install it

Comment: it solved my probleme thanks a lot

Comment: @OmarAmaoun, you're welcome

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you use some unix tool for this and invoke it in your bash process.

Check this out: [json command line processor](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

You probably want to investigate this one and you'll be probably good to go.

Comment: A software recommendation alone is not a very good answer for Stack Overflow. Show how it applies to the OP's problem.